# Track Angular2 Current Route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In my angular2 application, I have a shell component with a bunch of child components that are loaded through routing.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router, Route, RouteConfig, Location, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, OnActivate, ComponentInstruction} from 'angular2/router';


import {Home} from './components/home/home';
import {About} from './components/about/about';
import {RepoBrowser} from './components/repo-browser/repo-browser';

@Component({
    selector: 'seed-app',
    providers: [],
    templateUrl: 'app/seed-app.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    pipes: []
})
@RouteConfig([
    new Route({ path: '/home', component: Home, name: 'Home', useAsDefault: true }),
    new Route({ path: '/about', component: About, name: 'About' }),
    new Route({ path: '/github/...', component: RepoBrowser, name: 'RepoBrowser' })
])
export class SeedApp implements OnActivate {
    route: string;

    constructor(public router: Router) {
        this.route = this.router.hostComponent.name;

    }

    routerOnActivate(next: ComponentInstruction, prev:ComponentInstruction) {
        console.log('hi');

        this.route = next.urlPath;
    }

}
```

What I'm trying to do is track at this component level the currently selected route.  As you can see in my constructor, I tried getting `this.router.hostComponent.name` but that just returns SeedApp.

I also tried using the routerOnActivate function to get the one we're navigating to, but this never gets called.

Comment: What value exactly do you want? The URL, the name of the route, the name of the component (current, child, ...)?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer  Honestly, any of those.  I guess the name of the route would be easiest

Comment: you  want to know route name from central place ? or would if it be to know route name when  you go to particular route particular route???

Comment: I want to know the route name from a particular place.  I have the seed-app component that contains a template that can route to three other components (while the seed-app component is still active). Think of them as child components.  I need to know which one is currently active

Comment: I meant to ask is, if goto eg `about cmp', would it be fine to know it when about cmp is active?

Comment: FYI. your above code will not work as you have to mention all your components used for routing in `directives` section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can subscribe to router and can know current route your router routes to. In parent component or a component which contains `route.config` like this,

```
export class SeedApp implements OnActivate {
 constructor(router:Router)
  {
       this.router=router;
       this.router.subscribe((nextValue) => {
            console.log(nextValue);
       });
   ...    
  }
..
}
```

---

2) to particular route/component level by using `CanActive` hook like this,

```
import {CanActivate,OnActivate} from 'angular2/router';

@CanActivate((next: ComponentInstruction, previous: ComponentInstruction) => {
  console.log(next);
  return true;
})
export class About {
}
```

Comment: I ended up taking the first option.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Welcome. Enjoy `Angular2` !

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure how I feel about it yet.  I'm a much stronger Angular 1.x developer, but my boss wants me to do some research into Angular 2 to consider it for an upcoming project

Comment: You will fall in love with Angular2 as you start seeing beauty of angular2. way far better than `Angular1`. When I started I was like, Oh God! what is this? Why `Angular2` is not somewhat similar to `Angular1` ? But believe me, you're gonna love it. Yes at starting level its a bit confusing as it provides lots of things/ways to deal with. But have a happy journey !

Comment: I certainly am really enjoying everything I'm seeing so far, My only real concern is the fact that the community is so young that it's really hard to find examples of things that I want to do, like this question I asked, for example.

Comment: Yes may be. But I have following it since its `Alpha release` and I know many answers are available already.If you are going through primary stage of Angular2,  I think you will find a solution for your problem if your search a little more in SO and other site. still what you say is true about young community. .. Other than that questions on Angular2 are welcome here !

Comment: I really appreciate this. I tried so many methods to get the current route and this was the only one that worked! Why did you decide to omit a private tag in front of router, I'd like to know what it means either way.